# Graph visible outside X and Y axis

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am using achartengine for data that my application is continuously receiving over a socket connection. The point are plotted against time which is my x axis. Once the graph is in place a user can pan and zoom on the graph. Everything is buttery smooth. The only problem is that when the user zooms the graph, portions of the graph is also visible on the other side of x and y axis.

How do i restrict the graph from being visible outside the X and Y axis?

Here is a portion of my code.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
renderer.setShowGrid(true);
renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
renderer.setLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
renderer.setXLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
renderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
renderer.setShowLegend(false);

    renderer.setRange(new double[] { timeSeriesChart.getMinX(),
            timeSeriesChart.getMaxX(), 0/* minY */, maxY });

    renderer.setPanLimits(getChartLimit(
     isTimeChart, timeSeriesChart.getMinX(), timeSeriesChart.getMaxX(),
     (maxY*-1)+timeSeriesChart.getMinY(),
     maxY));
```

[image]

Comment: What version of AChartEngine are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0

Comment: Did you download it from here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list ?

Comment: Yes i did download it from there

Comment: Hi Dan, I figured this out. The problem was in the line - renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01)); changed it to renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE); and that did the trick.. somehow renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) was not working. Luckily i had a white background so no problems for me..

Comment: Thanks @Umesh but my background is not white :-(

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case (as mcd's) the background is not white (in fact it can contain graphics or a gradient) and thus Umesh's solution will not work. @Dan I know you are the original developer of ACE, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. I solved it by clamping my dataset to a max and min value. Of course in my case it worked because I was transforming the data I received from a server before placing it in my dataset.

```
TimeSeries mTimeSeries;

...
...

private void addValue(Date time, double val){
    if(val >= MAX_VALUE){
        val = MAX_VALUE;
    }
    if(val <= MIN_VALUE){
        val = MIN_VALUE;
    }

    mTimeSeries.add(time, val);
}
```

Comment: Did you allow zooming in your application? If so how did you handle that?

Comment: Nope. I have disabled zooming

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question relates specifically to panning/zooming.

Comment: You can simplify that code by doing `mTimeSeries.add(time, Math.max(MIN_VALUE,Math.min(MAX_VALUE,val)));`